# Is NestJs a right choice for a node.js beginner or should I do something with Express first?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sails.js, nestjs

I know `Nest.js` is on top of Express JS and can be on fastify, I have completed the express JS library project in the Mozilla (MDN) training site but for many reasons like the architecture of the app and discussions that I saw on web about problematic situations with express and modern JS like async-await, etc…

I searched for a more reliable choice: sails-js, nest and feathers came up, feathers were awesome but `Nest.js` had very good documentation and I avoided typescript for a while, but as for now it seems to be everywhere, and I hope with nest I could get to know it better and the practical use of it, at frontend I honestly could not find a good reason for using it besides it's a trend, except for angular 2 plus. Don't get me wrong angular is one of the reasons I hope to come around TS.

### Short Version

So this is my current situation as a frontend developer (vue & svelte mostly) a few months in NodeJS atmosphere (express and hapi) my question is: *should I stick to hapi & express or go with NestJs & alternatives like feathers and sails?*

Please forgive my lack of experience for writing in English.

Comment: i would stick to express/hapi. I work in hapi and nestjs both, on daily basis in my projects at work. I found nestjs more abstract than hapi. Somehow i find that hapi suits me better, in terms of syntax, simplicity and understanding, at this moment. If you just do simple projects for yourself for sake of practice, i would stick to simple solutions. Doing it for real apps, is another story. Experts will decide on that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community! Take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please don't forget to mark answers as accepted and upvote useful comments or posts.

Comment: @StefanZivkovic on my last job as a frontend dev I was working with people who had great experience in java,and there and then I saw how much of a programmer they truly are and not a programmer I am,I can't go start with somthing like java so I tought the OO framworks of js can help me become better and soon TS is in the way to that

Comment: None! Use Fastify+Nuxt and Ecmascript (for types there are good alternatives to clumsy typescript)

Comment: @CodeGust Acctually I ended up with nuxt 3 + adonis 5 on back-end, honestly I'm considering trying monolithic with edge templates or something like inertia to bring vue to adonis , Im a little disappointed on the issues that SSR meant to address on  SEO, but overall coding with vue 3 vite is a joy to say the least and adonis 5 documents really helped me, it's unbelievable how great people are in these comunities

Comment: @w3bsite good choice! you might also like WebComponents with Stenciljs - that might be the future. And those things can also be used with Vue for some scenarios.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nest.js & Typescript is a framework for enterprise-level applications which provides a clear structure and guidelines of how things should be.

So for the beginner pros are:

- OOP (SOLID) in TS/JS
- Introducing the latest LTS features of TS, like decorators, dependency injections, and so on.
- In build ESLint, prettier, and monorepo mod which can be activated via Nest CLI.
- Easy deployment via docker-compose for microservice architecture.

You can't achieve these things via such old frameworks like Express + (something else)

As for the cons:

- It's hard to understand why there is a `contoller` file, `service` file, and why there are multiple `module` files with `forRoot` and `forRootAsync` connections to DBs and so on.
- In time, it will be difficult to write/build projects w/o Nestjs because it's very good, but has a bit different pattern of programming.
- @Afaq mentioned that TS is the future (and Nestjs as well), but it's a bit wrong. JS as a native language always inherits the best available options from TS, as it did with CoffeeScript and so on. So one day in the future, you could wake up and look at your TS codebase as a legacy without appropriate support, while native technology goes forward.

Comment: about TS and the future I heard the same reasoning from other senior programmers,thank you for the answer

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to popular opinion, I'll suggest to get to know express a bit, make a plain simple server with JS and express (no fancy framweorks), convert it to TS. Get to know express library and how it works. NestJS abstracts a lot of the express'y' stuff. Its always good to know how it works under the hood.

I came from plain old JS + express to NestJS, and it feels good to know how it works under the hood.

It need not be a big app, just create a TODO with Auth,Validation and DB.

There is nothing wrong starting with NestJS though.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, You should go for nestjs. Typescript is the future. Once you are into typescript, you will love using it. Nestjs gives a very clean structure for building web apps. It can be compared to well established frameworks like LARAVEL, DJANGO in case of functionalities. yes it may not be as popular but it is growing. I really recommend using nestjs. The upside is, you don't always need Typescript for it. Nest can work fine with plain javascript as well.

Comment: yes it's true nestjs can be used without TS and its practical not just an advertising claim,thank you for taking the time to answer my question

Answer (score 1):

This question is over a year old and I'm sure OP's ship has already sailed, but for any new beginner reading this thread, build a basic application with expressjs first, and try rewriting it to typescript first.

Frameworks are only useful when you know what is abstracted and why it's abstracted. The only way you will be able to understand that is by working with the underlying technologies first.

Comment: this is true , I had a pretty smooth journey getting in back-end side and avoided confusion because I started with vercel serverless functions and in that environment the only focus was logic I used deta for database , it's a simple no-sql key value db, then went to express / fastify finally adonis 5 and PostgreSQL and vue/nuxt on front, of course I'm just using these tools and not saying I know them just learning by using them.